# insert/update table with two indexes

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this one:

```
column1 - primary
column2 - unique
column3
```

My query should behave like this:

- Insert if column1 and column2 are different
- Update column3 if both match
- Do nothing if only one matches

I've read about `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` but it doesn't seem to go well with my third request. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can't do this with only one query.  Is it okay to use two queries?

Comment: Yes i can use two queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work inserting if both are different and updating if both are the same.  This uses "1" as all three column values being inserted/updated (1,1,1):

```
insert into yourtable 
select distinct 1,1,1
from yourtable
where column1 <> 1 and column2 <> 1;

update yourtable
set column3 = 1
where column1 = 1 and column2 = 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b81d7/1)